# Unable to find tiff dll library using Qt

Tags: qt, dll, libtiff

I imported a [tiff library](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tiff.htm) in a Qt application, but I am having a problem when Qt tries to  load the TiffFilter.dll.
I tried to solve it using Developer Walker but it just made things worse.
The following error is generated: "TiffFilter.dll" 
not loadable

> "Cannot load library C:/tmp/trunk/etfshop-build-desktop/plugins/TiffFilter.dll: The specified module could not be found."

although the TiffFilter dll is present in that destination.
Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?
TY

Comment: Did you build tiff with the same compiler you are building your code?

Comment: Yes I did, same thing.

Comment: Did you build tiff as a dll or static library? If you built it as a dll did you put the dll in your plugins folder as well?

Comment: I built it as dll, and dll is in the plugins folder.

Comment: You may have to look at dependency walker.

Comment: Did you put the dll really in c:/tmp...? Unusual location for libraries.

Comment: yes I did. I created that folder.